# Range of $^*$ and range of $^∗$ have the same closure

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I have the following lemma and proof in my lecture notes ($\mathcal{R},\mathcal{N}$ denote range, kernel, respectively, and $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are Hilbert spaces).

[image]

I was hoping there was a simpler proof: for any linear operator between Hilbert spaces $B:X\to Y$, we have $X=\mathcal{N}(B)\oplus \overline{\mathcal{R}(B^*)}$, so I believe we have, for $A,B\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$,
$$\overline{\mathcal{R}(A^*)}\subseteq \overline{\mathcal{R}(B^*)} \iff \mathcal{N}(A)\supseteq \mathcal{N}(B) $$
Thus, to prove $\overline{\mathcal{R}(A^*A)}\supseteq \overline{\mathcal{R}(A^*)}$, we only have to prove
$$\mathcal{N}(A^*A) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(A)$$
which is easy, because if $A^*Ax=0$, then
\begin{align*}
\langle A^*Ax,x \rangle &=0\iff \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = 0,
\end{align*}
so $x\in \mathcal{N}(A)$.

Does this work?

Comment: Looks okay to me!  PS: Shouldn't you edit your title to reflect the relevance of the closure?  Perhaps "Range of $A^*A$ and range of $A^*$ have the same closure".

Comment: I think your solution looks perfectly fine! In fact, this is how I myself proved it when I first saw this result, a few years ago.

Comment: Just a very small nitpick. It should be explicitly stated that $X = \mathcal{N}(B) \oplus \overline{\mathcal{R}(B^{\ast})}$ is an *orthogonal* decomposition. You use that in the next line, so it's an important fact. You could also write that $\mathcal{N}(B) = \mathcal{R}(B^{\ast})^{\perp}$ instead of the decomposition $X = \mathcal{N}(B) \oplus \overline{\mathcal{R}(B^{\ast})}$. That's equivalent, and shows orthogonality without using words. But using words isn't a bad thing.